# Align two buttons center horizontally programmatically using constraint layout

Tags: android, button, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to programmatically use constraint layout to center two buttons of equal size horizontally at the center of the screen.  Here's what I have so far:

```
    val view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)


    buttonTrue = Button(activity, null, 0, R.style.NeutrifProText_BooleanButton)
    buttonTrue?.id = View.generateViewId()
    buttonTrue?.text = task?.booleanTrueLabel() ?: getString(R.string.button_yes)
    buttonTrue?.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    buttonTrue?.setOnClickListener { listener?.onTaskContinue(getAnswer(true)) }

    buttonFalse = Button(activity, null, 0, R.style.NeutrifProText_BooleanButton)
    buttonFalse?.id = View.generateViewId()
    buttonFalse?.text = task?.booleanFalseLabel() ?: getString(R.string.button_no)
    buttonFalse?.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    buttonFalse?.setOnClickListener { listener?.onTaskContinue(getAnswer(false)) }

    buttonTrue?.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    buttonFalse?.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    view?.task_constraint_layout?.addView(buttonTrue)
    view?.task_constraint_layout?.addView(buttonFalse)

    val idYes = buttonTrue?.id ?: 0
    val idNo = buttonFalse?.id ?: 0
    val descid = view?.task_description?.id ?: 0

    val clid = view?.task_constraint_layout?.id ?: 0
    val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
    constraintSet.clone(view?.task_constraint_layout)
    constraintSet.connect(idYes, ConstraintSet.TOP, descid, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, topMargin)
    constraintSet.connect(idNo, ConstraintSet.TOP, descid, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, topMargin)

    constraintSet.connect(idYes, ConstraintSet.START, clid, ConstraintSet.START, buttonSideMargin)

    constraintSet.connect(idNo, ConstraintSet.START, idYes, ConstraintSet.END, buttonSideMargin)
    constraintSet.connect(idNo, ConstraintSet.END, clid, ConstraintSet.END, buttonSideMargin)
    constraintSet.applyTo(view?.task_constraint_layout)
```

This results in:

[image: layout]

How do I get the buttons to be spaced evenly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created this layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see, there are no constraints, this is for simplicity since you are creating the `Button`s programmatically.

Now, in the `onCreate()` method (you can do it wherever you want), I do this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val constraintLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.myConstraintLayout)

    val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.button1, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START)
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.button1, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.button2, ConstraintSet.START)
    constraintSet.setHorizontalChainStyle(R.id.button1, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)

    constraintSet.connect(R.id.button2, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END)
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.button2, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.button1, ConstraintSet.END)
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
}
```

Note, this is the magic line:

`constraintSet.setHorizontalChainStyle(R.id.button1, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)`

So, your `ConstraintSet` code should look like this:

```
val clid = view?.task_constraint_layout?.id ?: 0
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(view?.task_constraint_layout)
constraintSet.connect(idYes, ConstraintSet.TOP, descid, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, topMargin)
constraintSet.connect(idNo, ConstraintSet.TOP, descid, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, topMargin)

constraintSet.connect(idYes, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, buttonSideMargin)
constraintSet.connect(idYes, ConstraintSet.END, idNo, ConstraintSet.START)
// This line does the magic
constraintSet.setHorizontalChainStyle(idYes, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)

constraintSet.connect(idNo, ConstraintSet.START, idYes, ConstraintSet.END)
constraintSet.connect(idNo, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, buttonSideMargin)
constraintSet.applyTo(view?.task_constraint_layout)
```

**EDIT:**

Verify your style `R.style.NeutrifProText_BooleanButton` is not applyng big margins to your buttons. Otherwise, if there is no space between your buttons, try to add some margins between them:

```
constraintSet.connect(idYes, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, buttonSideMargin)
constraintSet.connect(idYes, ConstraintSet.END, idNo, ConstraintSet.START, yourMarginValue /* Get it the same way you are getting buttonSideMargin */)
// This line does the magic
constraintSet.setHorizontalChainStyle(idYes, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)

constraintSet.connect(idNo, ConstraintSet.START, idYes, ConstraintSet.END, yourMarginValue /* Get it the same way you are getting buttonSideMargin */)
constraintSet.connect(idNo, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, buttonSideMargin)
constraintSet.applyTo(view?.task_constraint_layout)
```

This is the final result of my example:

[image: Constraint Layout Horizontal Chain Style]

Comment: Very nice.  I implemented and the two buttons are up against each other - what do I have to do to put a space between them?

Comment: @KristyWelsh, can you share an screenshot?

Comment: added screen shot.

Comment: Your style `R.style.NeutrifProText_BooleanButton` is maybe  applying some margins to your buttons. If that's not the case, then you could try by adding some margins, see the edited answer.